# Proof of $\overset {n+1} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(n, i-1)^2 = C(2n, n)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Question:

[image]

My attempt(proof by mathematical induction)
Let p(n) be the formula $\overset {n+1} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(n, i-1)^2 = C(2n, n)$

Show that p(n) is true for n=0
$\overset 1 \sum \limits_{i=1} C(0, 1-1)^2 =C(0, 0)^2=1=C(2\cdot 0, 0)$
so p(n) is true for n = 0

Show that for all integers $k≥0$, if p(n) is true for n=k, then it is true for n = k+1

Suppose $\overset {k+1} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(k, i-1)^2 = C(2k, k)$ for some integer k with $k≥0$...Inductive hypothesis

Then we must show that $\overset {k+2} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(k+1, i-1)^2 = C(2k+2, k+1)$....*

The left hand side of the equation * is
$\overset {k+2} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(k+1, i-1)^2$
$ = \overset {k+1} \sum \limits_{i=1} C(k+1, i-1)^2 + C(k+1, k+1)^2 $ by writing the last term separately
$= \overset {k+1} \sum \limits_{i=1}[C(k, i-1)+ C(k, i-2)])^2 +1$ by Pascal's formula

It doesn't seem to get better in this step. What should I do to advance from here? When looking at the equation, I feel C(n, r) = C(n, n-r) wouldn't work and the equation is not yet neatly simplified enough to use some sort of $(x+1)^2= x^2+2x+1$ because of the last term $1$ in the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$\tag{first}
(1 + x)^{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} x^{i}
$$
and
$$\tag{second}
(1 + x)^{2n} = \sum_{j=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{j} x^{j}.
$$
Now $x^{n}$ occurs with coefficient $\dbinom{2n}{n}$ in (second).

Since
$$
(1 + x)^{2n} = (1 + x)^{n} \cdot (1 + x)^{n},
$$
let us look at how the monomial $x^{n}$ occurs on the right hand side. This occurs from the products of all monomials $x^{i}$ from the first factor and $x^{n-i}$ from the second factor. Now the monomial $x^{i}$ occurs in (first) with coefficient $\dbinom{n}{i}$, and the monomial $x^{n-i}$ occurs with coefficient $\dbinom{n}{n-i} = \dbinom{n}{i}$.

Therefore
$$
\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \dbinom{n}{i} \dbinom{n}{n-i}
=
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \dbinom{n}{i}^{2}.
$$

---

Perhaps it could be noted that this is a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), which can be proved with no more effort.

Comment: I provided a combinatorial proof of Vandermonde's identity by selecting committees of size $n$ from a group of $n$ men and $n$ women.  The OP is insisting that the LHS does not count the number of such committees.  Would you mind taking a look at my proof on this page?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, rushing now, will try and do it later.

Comment: $(1+x)^{2n}$ equals not $\overset {2n} \sum \limits_{j=0} C(n, j)x^j$ but $ \overset {2n} \sum \limits_{j=0} C(2n, j)x^j$ by binomial theorem

Comment: @buzzee, misprint fixed, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the problem in this way : You have 2n objects colored with two collors , n is colored by  red and n is colored by black  and you want to choose  n objects. The expresions represent the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed,
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} \binom{n}{i - i}^2 = \binom{n}{0}^2 + \binom{n}{1}^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}^2$$
which we could write in the form
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$
by setting $k = i - 1$.  Thus, we wish to show that 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

The equation counts committees of size $n$ that are formed from a group of $2n$ people consisting of $n$ men and $n$ women in two ways.

The number of committees of size $n$ that can be formed from the $n + n = 2n$ available people is 
$$\binom{2n}{n}$$
Observe that if $k$ men are selected to serve on a committee, then $n - k$ women must serve on the committee.  The number of committees of size $n$ on which $k$ men and $n - k$ women serve is 
$$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k} = \binom{n}{k}^2$$
where we have used the identity 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n - k}$$
Since the number of men who serve on the committee can range from $0$ to $n$, the number of committees of size $n$ that can be formed from $n$ men and $n$ women is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$
Since we have counted the same committees in two different ways, we conclude that 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: You showed that
$$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k} = \binom{n}{k}^2$$ this can be achieved by using the equation in the example on the very top. 

But you didn't give a justification to 

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: I proved the result by showing that both sides of the equation are equal to the number of ways of selecting a committee of $n$ people from $n$ men and $n$ women.

Comment: the number of ways of selecting a committee of n people from n men and n women is not $\overset n \sum \limits_{k=0} [C(n, k)]^2$, but C(2n, n)

Comment: You understand the RHS of the equation.  For the LHS, observe that any committee of $n$ people formed from $n$ men and $n$ women must contain $k$ men and $n - k$ women.  The number of committees with $k$ men and $n - k$ women is $$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k} = \binom{n}{k}^2$$  That said, notice that $k$ can vary from $0$ to $n$.  Therefore, the set of all committees of $n$ people selected from $n$ men and $n$ women is $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: Note that this is the special case of [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) $$\binom{m + n}{r} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{m}{k}\binom{r}{n - k}$$ with $m = r = n$.